# Is it possible to attack RSA with a WalkSat derivative?

Tags: rsa, algorithm-design, factoring

We consider a large $n$-bit number $N$. We want to find a factor, if it admits any.

For $m$ taking values from $1$ to $n$, perform the following three steps (actually, for each $m$, perform many cycles, as described below).

1. Generate a random $m$-bit $x$.
2. If $x$ is a divisor of $N$, return $x$. 
   If ~$x$ is a divisor of $N$, return ~$x$. (~$x$ is the complementary of $x$,          basically flip every bit)
   Otherwise go to Step 3.
3. Choose a random bit $x_i$ and flip its value. Repeat Steps 2 and 3 for $t * m^2$ cycles, if necessary (where t is a fixed number).

This algorithm runs for a total of $C * n^3$ cycles (where the constant $C$ can be determined), and it either finds a divisor of $N$, or else says that $N$ is prime.

The probability of reporting a false prime will be as small as we want, as we have a random walk with two absorbing barriers.

This is basically a WalkSat - type algorithm, and we define the Hamming distance and the random walk on the space of $m$-bit binary strings, where $m$ takes values from $1$ to $n$. We can probably run the random walk search directly for n - bit numbers, without the m - bit levelling (the algorithm can be improved).

Is this a feasible factorization algorithm? Could it be used to crack RSA in practice?

Sept. 2017.   I found a fatal flaw in the mathematics long time ago  (this is an older,  edited question ).  This particular  algorithm is not efficient.

Comment: Your algorithm obviously doesn't work. You should try it.

Comment: Are you looking for the error in your algorithm? That's not really crypto, it's the math behind crypto, so you should ask on [math.se], or on [cs.se] rather than here. Or are you wondering about the consequences on crypto if there was a way to factor integers in polynomial time (in which case why describe this obviously broken algorithm in so much detail)?

Comment: Thank you for the above comments. I am pretty sure that the mathematics behind the algorithm is correct (if someone finds an error in the mathematics, I am sure that it is not obvious, look deeper). What are the consequences?

Comment: None, since your algorithm is way too slow and/or has a way too small probability of success. $\hspace{.68 in}$

Comment: re close votes: Whilst this algorithm is clearly flawed, I do not think the question is unclear. There is no ambiguity, just some mathematical errors.

Answer (score 9):

**No**, it not possible to attack RSA (and practical modulus size) with a WalkSat derivative, as far as we know, or using the algorithm in the question.

Problem with that algorithm is: in order to have a sizable/constant rate of success as $n$ increases, we have to repeat steps 2 and 3 not the stated $t\cdot m^2$ times, but rather $t\cdot 2^m$ times. That's because a divisor is found only when the random walk in steps 2/3 hits one of the few $m$-bit values that divides $N$, which we walk quasi randomly in a search space of $2^{m-1}$ values <sup><sub>(refers to an [earlier variant](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/11946/3) of the algorithm)</sub></sup>. The cost of the algorithm is thus not polynomial in $n$, but exponential in $n$. In fact, the algorithm is a randomized trial division, and has the same big-O cost.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, RSA is secure as we know it — although recommended key sizes are ever-increasing, as expected. Any seemingly-simple result that suggests a long-studied, well battle-hardened cryptosystem is insecure should throw up red flags.

As an exercise, I wrote up your algorithm in simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned x = 2385065119;

    srand(0); // deterministic randomness
    unsigned test = rand();
    char bit;
    while (x % test != 0) {
        do {
            bit = rand() % 32;
            test ^= (1 << bit);
        } while (x == test || test == 1);
    }

    printf("found factor: %u\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully I transcribed it correctly. It'll loop infinitely on prime numbers, however, so this is a simplified version.

I generated a random `x` with OpenSSL to factor. Note that this `x` is a mere 32 bits, *far* away from the size of numbers you'd find with modern-day RSA (which hover anywhere from 1024 to 4096 bits).

So, how fast is it?

```
$ time ./a.out
found factor: 890947
./a.out  10.85s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 10.882 total
```

This was compiled with `gcc -O3` and ran on a system with an Intel i5-3570k. Nearly 11 seconds. In comparison, Mathematica 8 completely factors the above `x` in 0.001606 seconds, as measured by `AbsoluteTiming@FactorInteger[2385065119]`. Hopefully this demonstrates the exceptional speed of modern-day factoring algorithms, and how yours compares to them.

That I used `srand(0)`, thereby making the program deterministic, severely affects the runtime length of your algorithm. Swapping over to `srand(time(NULL))`, the results were all over the place — sometimes it took as "little" as 1 second to find a factor, while at other times it took up to 22 seconds, in my (admittedly limited) testing.

If you're wondering where you've erred in your analysis, note the line

> Repeat Steps 2 and 3 for t * m^2 cycles

On average, it will take far longer than $m^2$ "cycles" to find a factor; with the random walk method you're employing, you're essentially doing random trial division, except you're not doing even the most basic optimizations like only testing numbers up to $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65058/discussion-on-answer-by-reid-is-it-possible-to-attack-rsa-with-a-walksat-derivat).

Answer (score -2):

RSA is secure currently as we do not have an efficient way to factorize the two primes ( within our lives anyways.. )
HOWEVER, if factoring becomes easier or when quantum computers become more large scale and accessible you can expect them to be factored within minutes.

Comment: Speak for yourself - I can factorize the primes in my head...

Comment: I found a fatal flaw in the mathematics long time ago,  this is a newly edited,  but much older question. This algorithm is not efficient.  The interested reader can read the new question "Assuming that NP = RP, how would this impact cryptography? "